# Android Studio: In-App-Billing v4 - How do you correctly iterate over skuDetails?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-billing

My app is a test app....

When I call my function to get shop item info, I actually get a skuDetails return of...

```
[SkuDetails: {"productId":"extra_lives","type":"inapp","price":"$0.99","price_amount_micros":990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"extra lives (Android2dGame)","description":"Gives the gamer more lives in game.","skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4IOHOfD5PIy8nRrLS2ywV8uP2xsU5e4aii8XmXoQbgp3cvJIheqJBFdmwAg9wAg"}, SkuDetails: {"productId":"tokens","type":"inapp","price":"$0.99","price_amount_micros":990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"tokens (Android2dGame)","description":"Tokens are an in-game currency.","skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4KHjvTaAB9I1zi3CCIOWBNwQN9QNtbd8leQbbhNj0vImVWSao6_SEABv6dURf9V"}]
```

That's when I print it to logcat as a string but when I try to iterate the skuDetails like so...

```
                        Log.d("prodid0", "         ");
                        for (SkuDetails sku : skuDetailsList){
                            shopItemsSku.add(sku);
                            ArrayList<String> curVals = new ArrayList<String>();
                            curVals.add(sku.getTitle());
                            curVals.add(sku.getSku());
                            curVals.add(sku.getPrice());
                            curVals.add(sku.getDescription());
                            curVals.add(sku.getType());
                            shopItemDict.put(sku.getTitle(), curVals);

                            Log.d("prodid1", sku.getTitle());
                            Log.d("prodid2", sku.getSku());
                            Log.d("prodid3", sku.getPrice());
                            Log.d("prodid4", sku.getDescription());
                            Log.d("prodid5", sku.getType());
                            Log.d("prodid6", "         ");
                        }
                        skuDetails = shopItemsSku.get(0);
```

Nothing will print to logcat but the log id of "prodid0."  It's like the for loop never runs but why?

I assume that's why my app is crashing when I start the purchase flow, because my skuDetails varable is not being fill with and actual skudetail.

Comment: If you want you could just create a JSONArray out of the sku response and get the items by using array.get(0). Use a for loop to go through them or make a hashmap, etc. Might not be the answer you're looking for, but it'll work

Comment: Could you or somebody give an example of the Json array....

Comment: This question is extremely unclear, as the example code does not feature anything of interest. Most likely, `skuDetailsList` is nothing but an empty array, no matter the JSON shown (wherever you may have obtained it from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...found the problem.

```
shopItemsSku.add(sku);
```

for some reason, that was breaking the loop.  It was defined as a List SkuDetails shopItemsSku.

I changed it to...

```
ArrayList<SkuDetails> shopItemsSku = new ArrayList<SkuDetails>();
```

Now, one of two things caused the issue...  (A) It could have been the fact ArrayList are supposed to grow and List are usually fixed...or (B) I never called new List<>() the first time.

I'm just surprised an exception did not raise because in Python, if something is wrong, it WILL let you know.

I'm already getting comfortable with Java but I know I will make little stupid mistakes like this time because I haven't been using it long at all but can fully use it because of 17 years of programming.

Google APIs are going to be a "beeoch",  that's unavoidable and I know it'll take time for that to stick.

However, I can truly say...Python is more powerful as a programming language and it has a cleaner syntax.  All that slow language talk is nonsense because micro processors are so fast now.  Python only takes time to start things up...like starting a car but when it goes to work, the results are instant...nothing slow about it.  The data structures are so well developed, you can litterally code any logic in python with very little thought about code work.

I clearly see as a Java programmer now, those days are over.  I just hope I can still manage the same level of perfection code wise, logic wise with Java as I did working with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you could do if the functions are not working. Since SKU responses are given in JSON, try

```
    try {
        JSONArray skuArray = new JSONArray(skuDetails.originalJson);
        for (int i = 0; i < skuArray.length(); i++) {
            String item = choices.getString(i);
            Log.d("SKU ITEM: " + item);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That should print out all the items in the JSONArray. You might have to get them as JSON objects or use get("price"), etc. If that doesn't work try new JSONObject(skuDetails.originalJson).get("price")

Comment: If I wanted to contruct and entry for skuDetails for passing to the purchase flow call, what is the correct format?  Is it a list with item info like [title, id, price, ect.....]?

Comment: Did some more research...  So Google is actually returning a Json object to you for skuDeatils....but their methods don't seem to work.  So am I going to have to add Json to my test project and parse the skuDetails using Json?  I'm guessing the purchase flow needs a Json object in order to start a purchase...most likely in the same format of the original skuDetails that returned from the item info call.  I could convert skuDetails to string and create my own java method to parse the data but I don't want to do that because google might change the structure or something.

Comment: @HoraceJohnson maybe it's because it's in test or because you're using the wrong id to fetch it, but the functions should work if you're correctly getting the SkuDetails. But if you want to use the GSON ('G' not 'J') by Google you could pretty easily just convert the returned JSON object into a java class and access it like that. I would recheck the billing library steps again

Comment: That's just it, I am getting a return because I can print the results to the log.d but it's like the for loop is not even registering because none of the log.d code inside the for loop prints out.  The purchase flow crashes the app, which confirms nothing is being passed to skuDetails varable (check code up top).

Comment: I think I have a solution for fixing the issue.  I just need to confirm one thing now....  The purchase flow asks for a skuDetail.  Is the formatting for that skuDetail a Json object?  Example, {"title":"extralives", "id":"extra_lives"......}  If that's the correct formatting for passing to the purchase flow, then I think I can solve everything.  I'm guessing my for loop is not working because the data that's placed inside the list isn't exactly in the correct format for a list....which could be why the for loop is having zero effect.

Comment: @HoraceJohnson I would probably try looking at the billing tutorial and redoing it maybe. You might need some special stuff when it's in test mode. The functions should be working

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this yet, but I have a theory....   If I create my own Java method that converts the returned SkuDetails in a string and then parse it down into key, value pairs per sku...  Then use that info to create a Json string (per sku) and then use Gson to create a skuDetails object to pass to the purchase flow...would it work.

```
    Example....

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    SkuDetails mItem = gson.fromJson("{\"SkuDetails\":{\"title\":\"extralives\",\"type\":inapp}}", SkuDetails.class);
    // of course you would have a full sku for one item
```

I'm hoping I can pass 'mItem' to the purchase flow function and get results.